# Yii2 How to use external PHP libraries

Tags: php, yii2

I want to use https://github.com/HelloFax/hellosign-php-sdk in Yii2 project so I followed following step

1 ) updated composer.json with  "hellosign/hellosign-php-sdk": "3.*@dev"      in require section

2) run composer update in CMD (I work with window 7)

so it downloaded required libraries (hellosign-php-sdk and libary) in vendor

3 ) include following code in controller file

```
$client = new HelloSign\Client('df754dd564e52fb2891a60eb2fea777b5320397********');  
$response = $client->getSignatureRequest('f6197945000616b383d4752*****');
if ($response->isComplete()) {
    echo 'All signers have signed this request.';
} else {
    foreach ($response->getSignatures() as $signature) {
            echo $signature->getStatusCode() . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Error 
Unable to find 'app\controllers\HelloSign\Client' in file: C:\wamp\www\yii2hellosign/controllers/HelloSign/Client.php. Namespace missing?

How to solve this issue, any help ?

Comment: try $client = new \HelloSign\Client('...');

Comment: @Tony , it solved issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the library use psr-0 autoload, so you need to prepend classname with \ , like this:

```
$client = new \HelloSign\Client('...');
```